# Connecting TableView within ViewController - self.tableView.reloadData() not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I'm a newbie learning iOS and Swift so apologies ahead of time. Currently I'm trying to setup a tableView within a viewController and display data in the cells in a portion of the screen. My current problem seems to be in reloading the tableView data after the Alamofire HTTP request in viewDidLoad() is called for numberOfRowsInSection(). Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class CourseDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var creditsLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var detailCourse: Course? {
        didSet {
            configureView()
        }
    }

    var course: Course!

    func configureView() {
        self.title = detailCourse?.abbr
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SectionCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        if let theCourse: Course = self.detailCourse as Course! {

            var abbr: String = theCourse.abbr!

            APIService.getCourseByAbbr(abbr) { (data) -> Void in
                self.course = Course(courseJSON: data)

                // Set labels
                self.titleLabel?.text = self.course.title!
                self.descriptionLabel?.text = self.course.description!

                if let creditsArray = self.course.credits {
                    let minimumCredit = creditsArray[0] as Int
                    self.creditsLabel?.text = String(minimumCredit)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return course.sections.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell
        let sectionCell = course.sections[indexPath.row]

        cell.termLabel?.text = sectionCell.term
        cell.timeLabel?.text = sectionCell.startTime
        cell.instructorLabel?.text = sectionCell.instructor

        return cell
    }
}
```

When I run, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I believe that the reason may be that I set up the tableView within the viewController incorrectly.

For the full project, here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/classmere/app/tree/develop

Comment: What line are you receiving the error on? Also make sure your "numberOfRowsInSection" is correct when the tableView is reloaded.

Comment: @air6199 return course.sections.count

Comment: Comment that line out for now and replace it with "return 0", what happens? I tried to access your project but it is missing this file.

Comment: I think i've figured out where the problem starts... Both self.detailCourse and self.course are nil. They are never assigned anything. Your "if let theCourse: ..." statement is never true so it cannot run. That checks if it does indeed exist but it returns false as it is currently nil. Not entirely sure if i'm correct but this is what it seems.

Comment: @air6199 For your first comment, it runs, but no data is displayed.

For your second comment, I think they're nil since they don't get a chance to be initialized since the code in APIService don't finish to return an object in time for the tableView methods to use.  I believe this may be because self.tableView.reloadData() is pointing incorrectly because of some sort of incorrect setup of a tableView within the viewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to unwrap an optional whose value is nil. When you declare the course property, since its an optional, its initial value is nil. Usually, optionals are declared with `?` and the compiler will prevent you from accessing the underlying value without checking if the value is still `nil`. In this case however, you've made the course property an expected optional:

```
var course: Course!
```

This is like saying "I know that `course` will always have a value and will never be `nil`". We don't know that however, since its value is `nil` until the Alamofire callback successfully completes.

To fix this problem, start by making `course` a standard optional:

```
var course: Course?
```

Now Xcode will complain that you're accessing `course` without unwrapping it, since your declaration of `course` no longer unwraps it.

Fix this by forcibly unwrapping everything in the Alamofire callback:

```
APIService.getCourseByAbbr(abbr) { (data) -> Void in
    println("APIService()")
    self.course = Course(courseJSON: data)

    // Notice we can access self.course using ! since just assigned it above
    self.titleLabel?.text = self.course!.title!
    self.descriptionLabel?.text = self.course!.description!

    if let creditsArray = self.course!.credits {
        let minimumCredit = creditsArray[0] as Int
        self.creditsLabel?.text = String(minimumCredit)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, we will use optional chaining to ensure we only access `course`'s properties if they exist:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell
    if let section = course?.sections[indexPath.row] {
        cell.termLabel?.text = section.term
        cell.timeLabel?.text = section.startTime
        cell.instructorLabel?.text = section.instructor
    }
    return cell
}
```

Finally in `numberOfRowsForSection` make sure to get the actual number of sections instead of always returning 50. We'll use the nil-coalescing operator to return 0 if `course` is `nil`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return course?.sections.count ?? 0
}
```

That should fix your problem!